# How can I self-destruct a Kubernetes pod automatically after 20 days?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, rancher, demo

I need to set up a kubernetes pod to create demo environments for clients of my web application, with a 20 day trial duration. After these 20 days, the pod should be automatically deleted, how can I make the pod self-destruct after 20 days?
I use Rancher to deploy my pods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using **two** ways, write your own code and run on K8s to check status which will delete the deployment (POD) after 20 days

Reference github : https://github.com/dignajar/clean-pods

There is no option for your pod to get auto-deleted.

Either you run **cronjob** at an interval of **20** **days** which will delete specific deployment but again in this case you have to **pass** deployment or pod **name** so cronjob has that variable.

**Example : 1**

use [delete_namespaced_pod](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md)

```
    from kubernetes import client, config
    from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException
    config.load_incluster_config() # if running inside k8s cluster config.load_kube_config()
    
    configuration = client.Configuration()
    
    with client.ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
        api_instance = client.CoreV1Api(api_client)
        
        namespace = '<Namespace name>'
        name = '<POD name>'  
api_instance.list_namespaced_pod(namespace)
        
        try:
            api_response = api_instance.delete_namespaced_pod(name, namespace)
            print(api_response)
        except ApiException as e:
            print("Exception when calling CoreV1Api->delete_namespaced_pod: %s\n" % e)
```

**Example : 2**

cronjob

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: cleanup
spec:
  schedule: "30 1 1,20 * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: kubectl-container
            image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
            command: ["sh", "-c", "kubectl delete pod <POD name or add variable here>"]
          restartPolicy: Never
```

**Extra**

You can also write **shell script** which run **daily** run few command to check the **AGE** of **POD** and delete if equal to **20** days

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Pending --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | awk 'match($5,/[20-9]d|[0-9][0-9]d|[0-9][0-9][0-9]d/) {print $0}'
```

**Update**

If you face any error for forbidden do create the service account and use that with cronjob

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa-name
  namespace: default

---
 
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: sa-role
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["list", "delete"]

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: sa-rolebinding
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: sa-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: sa-name
  namespace: default

---

apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: jobs
spec:
  schedule: "*/30 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: sa-role
```